# Solving a rubik's cube in java

Tags: java, rubiks-cube, finite-group-theory

I am, as the title says, writing a method of solving a Rubik's cube in java, and I am running into some difficulties.  I am trying to implement Kociemba's Algorithm and to do this I am following an article from [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/compcube.htm#kocal) (the specific part is about 2/3 of the way down by the way).  However, the code has an if statement with the conditional `subgoal reached`.  I don't understand how I can check this, because the subgoals are not really defined.  So, if someone could explain to me how I could check if the cube has reached the subgoal or provide some other tutorial, I would be very grateful.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please read [ask] -- specifically, the part where you have to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Note that a "MCVE" is _not_ just a snippet of your code as-is.

Comment: Hope this helps. http://symbolaris.com/orbital/Orbital-doc/examples/Algorithms/RubiksCube.java

Comment: Isn't this what you look for. https://github.com/cs0x7f/min2phase

Answer (score 1):

This does not really have anything to do with Java specifically. I will explain what a subgoal is. Essentially, to complete the cube, you want to convert it into a specific state. This is the endgoal. A subgoal is an intermediate state that you want to achieve. I'm assuming you know how to solve a Rubik's Cube. With a fully scrambled state, a subgoal might be to get all of the white edge pieces into place. So, you keep looping a phase until you have reached this subgoal, and then you start the next phase, which could be something like "place all of the white corners into the right place".

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Challenge Accepted